# convert String YYYY_MM_DD to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

For some reason the developer create the date column in my DB as a string and it is stored as `YYYY_MM_DD`.

Does anyone know how I can convert the `YYYY_MM_DD` to a date field via SQL.  e.g

```
2014_06_30 to 30/6/2014.
```

Or any other solutions

Thank you in advance

Comment: The programmer probably was unaware of [ISO 8601 date format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), which is supported by all modern databases, but still wanted to be able to sort the field chronologically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(100)='2014_06_30'

select CONVERT (DATETIME, REPLACE(@str, '_', '-'))
```

To convert it to format 30/6/2014, try:

```
select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(@str, '_', '-')), 103)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked.  When I run the sql I get 2014-06-30 00:00:00:000 how do I format that as 30/6/2014.

Comment: use DATE instead of datetime.

Comment: Try `select CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE(@str, '_', '-')), 103)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var myDate = '2014_06_30';
var myNewDate = select CONVERT (datetime, Replace(myDate,'_','/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @str NVARCHAR(100)='2014_06_30';
select RIGHT(@str,2)+'/'+SUBSTRING(@str,6,2)+'/'+LEFT(@str,4)
```